# Insautomatic insertion of images in a div class

Tags: php, image, slideshow

Goodmorning everyone,sorry in advance for my poor english...I'm using google translator!

i have this html code of a slideshow. I upload these 4 images from the folder indicated and make the slideshow.

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="photos/image1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active" />
    <img src="photos/image2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2" />
    <img src="photos/image3.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3" />
    <img src="photos/image4.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 4" />
   </div>
```

I have a webcam that periodically saves images in this folder and therefore I would need to upload them automatically without having to manually insert the lines of code (imageN...until N++).
To automate the reading of the images, which are constantly being created, I thought of using this php function to read the images in the photos folder.

```
<?php
function images($dir) {
 $files1 = scandir($dir);
   foreach ($files1 as $x=>$value)
    {
    if ($value == "." || $value == ".."){
        unset($files1[$x]);
     }
    }
     foreach ($files1 as $x=>$value)
      {
       echo "<li><img src=\"photos/$value\"></li>";
      }
     }
    ?>
```

and to call the function in this way

```
<div id="slideshow" >
<?php images (photos);?>
</div>
```

In manual mode the slideshow works, while in automatic way, with the search of the images through php function, it doesn't work. Can anyone help me out?
Thank you
mario

Comment: "*with the search of the images through php function, it doesn't work*" could you elaborate a bit more on 'what doesnt work'? Are you expecting the webpage to add more images to the DOM over time as new images show up on the server? If so, you may need longpolling to have an ajax get an updated list of image elements.

Answer (score 0):

The "does not work" means that it only loads the first image and then does not perform the slideshow. I expect that when I launch the html page to view the slideshow, the php utility will read all the images in the PHOTOS folder (this part works) and then create that "kind of matrix" that the DIV function uses to make the slide show.
If I launch the html page during the day, depending on the time, the images range from 1 to 250 so I need a dynamic reading and procedure that can be used at any time
Probably I am wrong the approach to the problem ... at the moment I have this idea and it is not said that it is the right one!